# get array index of newly pushed element

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/dPwQA/2/

says I push a new item into an array, after sorted, I want to get its index.

```
function sortInt(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}
numbers = [7,6];
numbers.sort(sortInt);
$('#text').text(numbers.toString());

$('button').click(function () {
    numbers.push('4');
    alert(numbers.indexOf("6")); // doesn't work
    numbers.sort(sortInt);
    $('#text').text(numbers.toString());
});
```

Comment: Are you voluntarily mixing strings and numbers in your array ? You have no "6", only 6.

Comment: You have a numerical value and you are looking for a string value

Comment: possible duplicate of [get indexOf newly pushed item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443603/get-indexof-newly-pushed-item)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes surrounding `6`.

It should be:

`alert(numbers.indexOf(6));`

Instead of:

`alert(numbers.indexOf("6"));`

**EDIT:**

When I meant remove quotes surrounding `6`, I should have said remove everywhere.

This should become:

`numbers.push(4);`

As opposed to:

`numbers.push('4');`

Comment: oic, now i want to check the newly input array item, it doesnt seem work here http://jsfiddle.net/dPwQA/4/

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
alert(numbers.indexOf(6));
```

also while pushing 4 you shold do like this

```
numbers.push(4)
```

instead of

```
numbers.push('4')
```

becacause '4' takes 4 as string not number.

Hope this helps...