# get indexOf newly pushed item

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

```
item = ['1,5,2'];
item.sortInt(item);
item.push('7');
```

//get the index number of 7? http://jsfiddle.net/dPwQA/6/

Comment: there is no `7` in item

Comment: @ArunPJohny I believe he means get the index of the item he just pushed. In this case `'7'`

Comment: in that case it will be `item.length - 1` because the pushed item will be added at the bottom of the array

Comment: The code in your fiddle has nothing to do with the code shown in your question. As I said in my (now deleted) answer, if all you want is the index of the last `.push()`ed item it will be `item.length-1`, but from the fiddle I see that you are sorting the array after adding the item, so what you really seem to be asking is "How do I get the index of item X in array Y?" This has nothing to do with how or when the item was added to the array.

Comment: please include as much relevant information as possible in your question, so that it stands alone.  external links are unreliable, and external links that conflict with your question are particularly confusing for everyone else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pushing the value as a **string** and alerting it as a **number**.

Change this: `numbers.push('4');` to this `numbers.push(4);`

### [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dPwQA/9/)

Comment: +1 Nice. This is the correct/simple explanation for this question.

Comment: why would you keep the O(n) `indexOf` rather than just using the array's new length?

Comment: @Eevee, OP is also sorting the array after the push(): `numbers.sort(sortInt);`

Comment: perhaps this should be a binsearch then.  what a weird question.  :)

Answer (score 2):

try `var index = item.push(7)-1;`
push method returns the length of the array and new item is always added at the end.

you can also use `item.indexOf(7)`. But it return the index of first occurrence of 7 so it is not useful when you have duplicate entries in your array.

Note: `item = ['1,5,2'];` will add a string.
should add like `item = [1,5,2];`

Comment: This is not the problem. Check OP's Fiddle (question didn't have whole code)

Comment: No it doesn't return the index, it returns the length: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push see "Returns"

Answer (score 1):

pull a variable out for the newly pushed item, it will contain the length of the array, so subtract one from that.

Like this:

```
var array = [];
var item = array.push('a');
console.log(item); //logs "1"
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/34KB9/

**EDIT**: for the downvoters:

```
var array = [];
var item = array.push('a');
var item2 = array.push('b');
console.log(item-1); //0
console.log(item2-1); //1
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/34KB9/1/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

When you push the number it should of integer and not string so remove the quotes

```
$('button').click(function () {
    numbers.push(4);//remove the quotes
    numbers.sort(sortInt);
    $('#text').text(numbers.toString());

    getIndexOfNewlyItem();

});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Somnath_k/dPwQA/7/)

Comment: _"The index of newly pushed value will be always 0"_ - No it won't. `.push()` adds to the _end_ of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your code

you are pushing `numbers.push('4');` String

and alerting `alert(numbers.indexOf(4));` Integer

Due to this type mismatch you are getting `-1`.

Solution

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dPwQA/10/)
`numbers.push(4);` push as Integer

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Description) :

> indexOf compares searchElement to elements of the Array using strict equality (the same method used by the ===, or triple-equals, operator).

If you insert a string in your array (e.g : `item.push('4')`) and search for a number (e.g : `item.indexOf(4)`), it won't be found.

You need to make sure what you look for has the same type as what you insert : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dPwQA/11/)

If your input is a variable, and you are not sure of its type, here are some common ways to force the conversion to an int, or a number :

```
var f = +x; // f will be a number, float or int,
            // will be NaN if x isn't a valid number
var i = x|0; // i will be an integer number,
             // will be 0 if x isn't a valid number,
             // floor(x) if x is a valid float
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dPwQA/12/)

Answer (score 0):

`item.length - 1` will always be the index of the last item.  `Array.push` also returns the new length of the array, so you could subtract from that.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `Array.push(item)` the item is always inserted at the `last position`, it will be the last item so

```
The index number will be item.length - 1.
```

also if you want to push integer then

```
numbers.push(7); // no need to use quotes('')
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but yes you missed that the OP gave a really poor explanation of what they're doing. The code in their fiddle is quite different to that in the question and they're sorting the array after pushing the item in, so...

Comment: No idea who downvoted, but I compensated. You're correct in what you say even if the OP had a terrible description of his problem.

Comment: @nnnnnn yup i replied according to the title, didn't checked the fiddle

Comment: Yes. I too replied without checking the fiddle until I saw that other answers were talking about things not mentioned in the question. I ended up deleting my answer and (mildly) telling off the OP in a comment. No idea why the question got upvoted.